# Gas estimation error... The transaction will likely fail... Do you want to force sending

Tags: solidity, remix, gas

I was messing around YouTube and bumped into this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhkb9G2SyVw&ab_channel=Web3Tutorials

I tried the code and it let me run the bot on remix. After a day of it not producing any ETH i tried to withdraw the funds which was around 0.5 ETH. It came up with an error to say that i needed least 1 ETH at present market conditions. Wait for the market to cool down or fund the contract with more ETH. As i dont know anything about coding, i put another 0.5 ETH in to possibly be able to withdraw. Then it mentions that i now need at least 2 ETH which is strange and when i check the contract address the value of ETH is still in there but i dont know if i can be able to withdraw the ETH from the contract address i have created.

This is the code i used: https://pastebin.com/raw/GpRU5E6v

My contract address is https://etherscan.io/address/0x5729Ff0D0c1592a3ebb28C6880F25187eC0D466a/advanced#internaltx

Just to mention too, the failed transactions at the address is me trying to withdraw my ETH and paying the highest amount of gas fees to get my ETH back into my Metamask account. I have looked on YouTube to possibly see if i can retrieve it manually but on the 'Contracts' tab at the bottom it doesnt give me the option to 'Write a contract' so i can withdraw the fees directly but i assume that i cant as it is a smart contract and i need to verify and publish the code.

Any help is appreciated, Thank You.

Edit: Found out that is was a scam which is a lesson learned to not touch anything you dont understand. Thank you for the help Nal Luksic

Comment: My apologies for not knowing where to simply post a reply. I have the same problem, can't withdraw my funds from the Contract's MetaMask wallet. There is no way around this, right? The ethereum is still all there, that's what's also perplexing; why didn't the scammer withdraw them himself?

Comment: That is what is spinning my head around too. My guess is that they are waiting to see if the victim would put more ETH in due to the prompt when they try to withdraw it as I did, and take it when they want to since they have direct access to it and its such a shame but its a lesson for both of us to learn from and grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, but you got scammed. Front running does not work like this. Front running bots are scripts that work from off-chain, not smart contracts.

You should never use code, which you do not understand especially if it promisses you profit.

I didn't go into details, because its designed in such a manner that complicates things for no apparent reason, which is an indicator that contract is a scam.

But from what I was able to find out, theres an attacker wallet: `0xBcF87A18e05e562BD307d76682677d2388973cc6` and the next time you call start method, the contract will send all the funds to the attacker (am not sure about this, but this is what happened to some other victim): `https://etherscan.io/address/0x1f2e5eef0de4e9ab7651ffcd790070c254ba90fd`

Unfortunally there is nothing you can do at this point.